# Machine learning for time-series forecasting

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python, real-time

I am new to machine learning and have been trying to learn. I am forecasting AQI using ExtraTreesRegression model in Python. My training and testing results are coming good. While testing my model my r2 score is 90 but when I used the same model for the real-time application the r2 score degrade to 53. what is the issue taking place?

Another question is I am using train_test_split function to split my time-series data into train and test set. This function provides me shuffled data on which my testing r2 score is 90 but when I disable the shuffling option in the train_test_split function my r2 score degrade to 53. why this is taking place? How does the shuffling affects on time-series forecasting? Is shuffling is beneficial for time-series or not?

Comment: Shuffling a dataset for time-series forecasting is not a good practice. It would be helpful if you could provide an MCV of your issue and data.

Comment: Use a TimeseriesSplitter instead of train_test_split. Your performance now is overestimated, as you have data leakage

Comment: @jonnor thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Ic3fr0g thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use regression algorithms for forecasting. There's a good explanation of how to adapt regression algorithms to forecasting problems [here](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/41231210/Machine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser20160114-28513-1pqgoe9.pdf20160115-19908-phg1xc.pdf?1452888125=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DMachine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser.pdf&Expires=1624039511&Signature=f8rYTwXKMczX236zAdZiWzfHdeyaocgzgnvIOb4WpgZW3TOE45HUeYakljIdroKhc0soWRGNX1W0VAnadfBbIYNeoXw3Ces%7EcAb%7E5hPcmuu3%7Eu2Wa1cLBDv4uhxQ9841YT-rTkQvkInLcBLZCqSwUdWhgqF9SG4C24uApy5uX8EG%7EvQ4kKrVVZzloBep9XulbWGC-BSt%7Ew%7EuUUxGcTWv05h5hBddm63FCDkPwcDzkYEno0YwnaPUoNSRrdUXA1CYAhpj%7EdA2BnKljQqkqmCI55OC5pS8gKcVN3fEs1tYXyKYcgb6cFrnXS-85kRPv3wILRrhc4DiyCJtE6ymfTEhiA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA).

As stated in the comments, you need to make sure you properly evaluate your forecasting algorithms. When you use `train_test_split` you random shuffle and split your data. Instead you should only use past data to fit your algorithm and then evaluate against future data.

If you're interested, we're developing a toolbox that extends scikit-learn for exactly these use cases. So with [sktime](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime), you could simply write:

```
import numpy as np
from sktime.datasets import load_airline
from sktime.forecasting.compose import make_reduction
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.performance_metrics.forecasting import mean_absolute_percentage_error

y = load_airline()  # load 1-dimensional time series
y_train, y_test = temporal_train_test_split(y)  
fh = np.arange(1, len(y_test) + 1)  # forecasting horizon
regressor = ExtraTreesRegressor()  
forecaster = make_reduction(regressor, window_length=10)
forecaster.fit(y_train)
y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh)
print(mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, y_pred))
>>> 0.17668623103710565
```

Comment: That first link does not work!

Comment: @Tylerr I fixed the link and updated the code too to reflect the most recent release.